# I need a random baby name generator in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a file with 18239 names I would like a batch file that chooses a random name from that file if I press enter. So it would be like, "You got..." press enter "Amanda". I've looked around everywhere and no one seems to know how to make it choose from a random line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
cls
:start
cls
Set _File=names.txt
Set /a _Lines=0
For /f %%j in ('Find "" /v /c ^< %_File%') Do Set /a _Lines=%%j
SET /a _Rand=(%RANDOM%*%_Lines%/32768)
for /F "skip=%_Rand% delims=" %%i in (%_File%) do set "xprvar=%%i"&goto nextline
:nextline
echo You got %xprvar%
set /a _Rerun=1
set /p _Rerun=""
if not '%Rerun%'=='q' goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

please provide sample of the file. is it comma separated or based on new line.

if it based on new line you can use the below java code:

```
public static String getRandomLine(String path) throws IOException{
    long lineCount;
    try ( Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {
        lineCount = stream.count();
    }
    String line;
    try ( Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {
        long randomLine = (long) (new Random().nextDouble() * lineCount);
        line = stream.skip(randomLine).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
    return line;
}
```

Comment: This is a question about the batch scripting language; what does Java have to do with this?